# Использовать в ответах REST свободные коды состояния HTTP

Tags: http, api, rest

Пришла в голову идея использовать в ответах REST свободные коды состояния HTTP для нужд конкретного REST API.

Например:

- 470 или 770 -"User account not found"
- 471 или 771 -"User account
  avatar not found"

Не нашел критики такого подхода.
Это хорошая идея?

Какие проблемы кроме совпадения с новыми кодами стандарта могут быть?

Comment: https://habr.com/post/265845/ хорошая статья именно о минусах `restful api` использовать спецефические коды такие как 470, 770 и т.д я б не советовал, не все браузеры их распознают и поддерживают. Результат может быть неожиданным от их использования.

Comment: Спасибо, Arendach